# Selecting a table row in javascript causes IE8 to fail

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
document.getElementById("row").innerHTML = "";
```

This causes IE to raise "Unknown runtime error".

I know this is a known bug, but is there any workaround (except the obvious using a div instead).

Works fine in all other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you provide the HTML code you use? Is there a reason you can't use jQuery?

maybe you could use:

```
 document.getElementById('table1').deleteRow(_row.rowIndex);
```

Comment: The code is there.  I can use jQuery, but this is a very simple function

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "nuking" the row like that, just hide it:

```
document.getElementById("row").style.display = "none";
```

Same final result (row will disappear from view) without messing too much with the DOM.

Edit: another way to "clear" the element is:

```
var row = document.getElementById("row");
while (row.childNodes.length > 0)
    row.removeChildNode(row.childNodes[0]);
```

Should be as cross browser as possible - [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/nZ7D5/).

Comment: Because I rebuild it later, it needs to start blank.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've just used jQuery to select instead.  Horrid IE.

Comment: Cheers, jQuery is indeed better as you don't have to do all the dirty work anymore. :)